# Doxygen test plan generation

Tags: testing, doxygen, testcase, test-plan

Does Doxygen have the capability to generate test plans from a number of test cases?
This would be much like Atlassian Jira Plug-in called "Zephyr"

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen provides the command '@test', which starts a paragraph to describe a test case and creates an additional "Test" index. This in combination with the capability to create custom commands and create PDF files via Latex should help to create test plans with doxygen. I already used this to document my Unit Tests.